# How to solve " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver.firefox' "?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I have Anaconda installed on my mac and selenium comes preinstalled with it. But leaving nothing to chance, I installed it myself using `sudo pip3 install selenium`. Then I downloaded the gecokdriver (for Mozilla Firefox) and chromedriver files.

Now when I try `import selenium`, it works fine.

When I try `from selenium import webdriver`, it throws an error saying:

```
>  File "<ipython-input-22-93833772b63f>", line 1, in <module>
>     from selenium import webdriver
> 
>   File
> "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py",
> line 18, in <module>
>     from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
> 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver.firefox' `
```

As the error states, the file -  /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/__init_ _.py tries to call `from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa`. But I think that there is no file or anything related to ".firefox.webdriver " on my mac and this is why it is throwing an error.

How do I fix this!?

Comment: What is the output of `ls /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/`?

Comment: @ipaleka it's output is blackberry  edge        phantomjs   support
__pycache__ chrome      ie          remote      webkitgtk
android     common      opera       safari

Comment: Exactly as in my installation with that crucial difference that I have `firefox` too. That's strange, try to reinstall selenium.

Comment: @ipaleka is there a way you could send me that firefox file online so i'd manually put it there

Comment: Wedll, afaik that's basically [this directory](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox), but I believe some extra things are compiled upon installation. If you don't have Firefox installed, try first to uninstall selenium, install Firefox, and then install selenium.